# java.sql.Time value changing after JibX binding

Tags: java, xml, jibx

I came across very surprising behavior of java.sql.Time today.
My setter method sets the time correctly to the property.

But when that property gets marshaled using JiBX, The output in XML is something as Below.

> actual Time : 05:24:35
>
> after marshaling : 142:52:38.601

I want the actual time format to be retained in the xml.
How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Tushar,

Please file a bug report at https://github.com/jibx/jibx/issues

Be sure to include an example. Also, ensure that you are using the latest release, 1.3.1

Thanks